# Gradle Custom buildScriptRepository methods

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I would like to make a custom `buildScript` repository method so I can easily reference our internal maven repo.  Right now I'm required to declare a `maven` block everywhere we use our plugin.

Here is the current setup

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://myNexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/My-Release' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example.plugin:my-plugin:1+'
    }
}
```

What I would like to do is something like this

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        myReleaseRepo()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example.plugin:my-plugin:1+'
    }
}
```

How can I make a method available to create a repository anywhere we may use the plugin in the future?

Comment: Hmm, I know that you can add custom extensions that apply repositories or dependencies similar to what you're asking. See: http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2013/05/gradle-goodness-extending-dsl.html But you want to put a custom repo handler in the buildscript block itself. I wonder if it can be done at all..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to add a repo to an init script which would then apply to all gradle invocations that use the init script - without having to individually declare your maven repo in each build.gradle.

#### Solution 1:

Partial solution, does not do *exactly* what you're asking for. In `init.gradle`:

```
allprojects{
    buildscript{
        repositories{
            maven{ url 'http://myNexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/My-Release' }
        }
    }
}
```

Then your `build.gradle` can skip buildscript repo declaration entirely:

```
buildscript {
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example.plugin:my-plugin:1+'
    }
}
```

#### Solution 2:

In fact, you can even move your buildscript classpath declaration to init and have the plugin apply to all projects that use the init script:

beefier `init.gradle`

```
allprojects{
    buildscript{
        repositories{
            maven{ url 'http://myNexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/My-Release' }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.example.plugin:my-plugin:1+'
        }
    }
}
```

gives you a lighter `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'my-plugin'
```

I tried to, but apparently you cannot move the apply line to `init.gradle` as well. see [this defect](https://issues.gradle.org/browse/GRADLE-2407).

#### Solution 3:

I retract what I said in the comment above, I figured out how to do *exactly* what you're asking for. Apparently you can create extensions for the buildscript block using the initscript. However I still prefer solution2, because it gives you a cleaner build.gradle.

To create a buildscript extension, in your `init.gradle`:

```
class customRepos {
    def buildscript
      customRepos(buildscript) {
        this.buildscript = buildscript
    }

    void addMyRepo() {
        buildscript.repositories {
            maven{ url 'http://myNexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/My-Release' }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    extensions.create('myRepo', customRepos, buildscript)
}
```

which then allows you to do this in your `build.gradle`

```
buildscript{
    myRepo.addMyRepo()

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.example.plugin:my-plugin:1+'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'my-plugin'
```

Comment: Solution 3 is right on track...  Had to modify the wrapper to add the `-I init.gradle` command line arg to make sure it's always added for the projects I want.  Thanks!

Comment: ended up using `apply from: 'init.gradle'`.  Modifying the `gradlew` script meant the IntelliJ would fail to sync as it doesn't use `gradlew`

Comment: You can make intelliJ user gradlew `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Gradle -> use gradle wrapper`

Comment: Great question + great answer! Thanks! Note: there are several options for init scripts: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/init_scripts.html#sec:using_an_init_script

Answer (score 4):

Another solution is to add custom methods on RepositoryHandler using some Groovy goodness. Just chuck this in `~/.gradle/init.gradle`

```
RepositoryHandler.metaClass.myReleaseRepo = {
    delegate.maven {
        name 'myReleaseRepo'
        url 'http://myNexus:8081/nexus/content/repositories/My-Release'
    }
}
```

After that, you can use it just as you described:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        myReleaseRepo()
    }
}
```

Metaclasses in Groovy are just great. The delegate in this case is pretty much like the javascript `this`. This code is essentially using the `RepositoryHandler` instance (delegate keyword) and just calling `repositoryHandlerInstance.maven(name, url)`.